# python django pymysql query formatting datetime output?

Tags: python-3.x, django

python3.8
sql

```
sql="select * from target"

def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    data = dictfetchall(cursor)
return data
```

data output is

```
[{
           
            "name": "tom",
            "congestion_level": null,
            "arrival_flow": 15.0,
            "ctime": "2020-04-11T12:00:00"
        },
        {

            "name": "jack",
            "congestion_level": null,
            "arrival_flow": 25.0,
            "ctime": "2020-04-11T12:00:00"
        }]
```

`ctime` this fields has `T`，if I remove `T` I need run following code:

```
def datetime_to_str(old_dict_list):
    for old_dict in old_dict_list:
        for x, y in old_dict.items():
            if isinstance(y, datetime.datetime):
                old_dict[x] = datetime.datetime.strftime(y, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return list(old_dict_list)
```

I think my method is not pythonic,I don’t want to use django orm because of the complex sql statement

Comment: I don't understand: you want the field `ctime` as string or as datetime object? Because it looks like it already is a string.

Comment: So you're on MySQL? Then you can format in the `select`, i.e. `select name, congestion_level, arrival_flow, date_format(ctime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') from target`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MySQL you can format `ctime` using [`date_format`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in your `select` statement:

```
sql = "select congestion_level, arrival_flow, date_format(ctime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') from target"
```